# Pidgin randomly starts loading fonts

Tags: pidgin

For some reason, Pidgin sometimes randomly starts loading *all* of the fonts on my computer. Needless to say, it takes quite a long time, and it freezes while that happens.

I have no idea what triggers this.

Any idea on how to prevent it?

#### Edit:

I just caught a stack trace:

```
[...]
23, msvcrt.dll!fread+0x18
24, freetype6.dll!FT_Outline_Embolden+0x305
25, freetype6.dll!FT_Get_X11_Font_Format+0x1d2f
26, freetype6.dll!FT_Get_X11_Font_Format+0x2bcb
27, freetype6.dll!TT_RunIns+0x31c4
28, freetype6.dll!FT_Load_Glyph+0x145
29, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcFreeTypeCharIndex+0x2b5
30, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcFreeTypeCharIndex+0xb49
31, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcFreeTypeCharSetAndSpacing+0x2f
32, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcFreeTypeQueryFace+0x11f7
33, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcFreeTypeQuery+0x7d
34, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcFileIsDir+0xb1
35, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcFileIsDir+0x323
36, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcFileIsDir+0x414
37, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcConfigReference+0x1ba
38, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcConfigBuildFonts+0x3a
39, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcInitLoadConfigAndFonts+0x1f
40, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcInit+0x1d
41, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcConfigGetCurrent+0x1c
42, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcConfigSubstituteWithPat+0x616
43, libfontconfig-1.dll!FcConfigSubstitute+0x27
44, libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll!pango_ft2_font_map_get_type+0xd7
45, libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll!pango_fc_font_key_get_context_key+0x50
46, libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll!pango_fc_font_map_add_decoder_find_func+0x2055
47, libpango-1.0-0.dll!pango_context_load_font+0x8a8
48, libpango-1.0-0.dll!pango_itemize_with_base_dir+0x77
49, libpango-1.0-0.dll!pango_layout_set_text+0x3dc
50, libpango-1.0-0.dll!pango_layout_set_text+0x18d1
51, libpango-1.0-0.dll!pango_layout_get_pixel_extents+0x71
52, libpango-1.0-0.dll!pango_layout_get_pixel_size+0x2a
53, guifications.dll+0x8d7e
54, guifications.dll+0x934a
55, guifications.dll+0xa716
56, guifications.dll+0x3c45
57, guifications.dll+0x4f82
58, libpurple.dll!purple_marshal_VOID__POINTER_POINTER_POINTER_POINTER_UINT+0x34
59, libpurple.dll!purple_signal_emit_vargs+0x9b
60, libpurple.dll!purple_signal_emit+0x27
61, libpurple.dll!serv_got_im+0x11d
62, libjabber.dll!jabber_send_typing+0x3e2
63, libjabber.dll!jabber_message_parse+0x70d
64, libjabber.dll!jabber_process_packet+0x1a6
65, libjabber.dll!jabber_parser_process+0x289
66, libxml2-2.dll!xmlParseNotationType+0x491
67, libxml2-2.dll!xmlParseMarkupDecl+0x545
68, libxml2-2.dll!xmlParseChunk+0x1a7
69, libjabber.dll!jabber_parser_process+0x34
70, libjabber.dll!jabber_unregister_account+0x3cc
71, pidgin.dll!pidgin_eventloop_get_ui_ops+0x110
72, libglib-2.0-0.dll!g_main_context_dispatch+0x19b
73, libglib-2.0-0.dll!g_main_context_prepare+0x8b5
74, libglib-2.0-0.dll!g_main_loop_run+0x164
75, libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll!gtk_main+0xa0
76, pidgin.dll!pidgin_main+0x4c8
77, pidgin-portable.exe+0x2226
78, pidgin-portable.exe+0x2fc9
79, pidgin-portable.exe+0x10a7
80, pidgin-portable.exe+0x1123
81, kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
82, ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
83, ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36
```

So it seems like it has to do with the *guifications* plugin...

Comment: What plugins do you have enabled?  One of these is probably the culprit.

Comment: @Paul: I have Guifications, Infopane Options, Last Seen, Message Notification, Message Timestamp Formats, Psychic Mode (!), Send Button, Separate and Tab, and Timestamp, but I have no way of testing this since I can't reproduce the problem on my own.

Comment: You can't reproduce the problem?  Isn't this a problem with your machine?

Comment: @Paul: I mean I can't reproduce it deterministically -- it happens like once a week; I don't know how to reproduce it intentionally.